# Gradle error: Could not find method add() for arguments

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

I'm using gradle **2.12** and I have a multi-module **java** gradle project structured in the following manner -

```
parentProject  
|__module1  
   |__src  
   |__build.gradle  
|__module2  
   |_src  
   |__build.gradle  
|__build.gradle
```

The settings.gradle is defined as -

```
include "module1"
project(":module1").projectDir = file("path/to/module1")

include "module2"
project(":module2").projectDir = file("path/to/module2")
```

module2 depends on module1 and the dependency is required in the buildscript. I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/clmarquart/1976155) example which shows a workaround as gradle doesn't allow classpath dependencies of projects in the buildscript. What I did in module2's build.gradle is -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

    project.getTasks().add([name: "module1", type: GradleBuild]) {
        buildFile = '../module1/build.gradle'
        tasks = ['pluginJar']
    }.execute()
}

apply plugin: java

dependencies {
    // project specific dependencies
}
```

I started getting the following error -

```
Error:(13, 0) Could not find method add() for arguments [{name=module1, type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild}, build_c3cjs9wfepa1xdklituv2tk9i$_run_closure1$_closure3@51bcefbf] on task set.
```

I searched for similar errors and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870567/add-sourcesjar-task-to-custom-gradle-plugin) solution, but it didn't help me.

This is how my project structure is, and I cannot change it to make module1 an independent build.

Please advice. Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method you try to invoke would be defined in [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html). As you can see it's not.

Try:

```
project.getTasks().create(name: "module1", type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = '../module1/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['pluginJar']
}
```

As you can see I've omitted call to `execute` - you should never call a task directly.

Comment: Thanks Opal for replying! Here's the thing, the module1 here is a gradle-plugin, and after I try your suggestion it now says during the build that it cannot find the plugin specified.

Comment: @AdeeJ and how about calling it directly, I mean invoking `execute()`?

Comment: The build loops infinitely. Whenever the build.gradle of a module is invoked, gradle evaluates all the modules using their respective build.gradle file. And when module2’s build.gradle gets evaluated, it in turn invokes module1’s build script.

Comment: @AdeeJ I doubt if I can help without runnable example.

Comment: I've added the example code here - https://github.com/ajuwala/gradle-multimodule-example

Please check and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: As far as I see this is just not possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775023/how-to-use-classes-from-a-neighbouring-subproject-during-configuration-phase) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334174/how-to-add-java-source-onto-gradle-buildscript-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Opal, this is not possible.